# Error while running custom PIG Load function

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Pig and Java and am trying to write a custom Load function which will only give me specific rows from my data-set. Unfortunately, I am getting an error which I am not able to understand. Can someone please help me out in understanding this error. Please let me know if you need any other data from my side. Many Thanks.

```
My version of Pig is 0.13.0
My Linux version is Ubuntu 14.04.1
```

My Code:

```
package udf;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.pig.LoadFunc;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;
import org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigSplit;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;

        public class extract extends LoadFunc{

            private RecordReader reader;
            private int count = 0;
            private TupleFactory mytuplefactory;

            public extract(){
                mytuplefactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
            }

            @Override
            public InputFormat getInputFormat() throws IOException {

                return new TextInputFormat();
            }

            @Override
            public Tuple getNext() throws IOException {


                        Tuple myTuple = null;
                        Text myText = null;

                try{

                    boolean notdone = reader.nextKeyValue();

                    if(!notdone){
                        return null;
                    }

                    while( reader.nextKeyValue()){
                        Text t = (Text) reader.getCurrentValue();
                        if(t.toString().equals("People aged 18-64"))
                            count = 6;
                        if(count <= 6 && count > 0){
                            myText = (Text) reader.getCurrentValue();
                            break;
                        }
                        count--;
                    }

                    if(myText != null){

                        myTuple = mytuplefactory.newTuple(myText);
                        return myTuple;

                    }else
                        return null;

                }catch(Exception e){
                    throw new ExecException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void setLocation(String location, Job job) throws IOException {

                FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, location);

            }

            @Override
            public void prepareToRead(RecordReader reader, PigSplit PigSplit)
                    throws IOException {

                this.reader = reader;
            }
        }
```

My Sample Test Data :

```
All People  "281,113"   *****   "100,094"   946 "84,028"    769 "63,736"    721 "23,176"    379 "10,079"    247 
  .Insured (any type)   85.25   0.23    87.10   0.34    85.08   0.42    82.49   0.38    84.41   0.67    87.72   0.66    
    ..Privately insured (alone or  in combination)  73.46   0.29    79.43   0.41    76.51   0.46    69.31   0.46    57.98   0.81    50.45   1.21    
    ..Medicare  12.98   0.06    3.48    0.11    8.34    0.22    19.05   0.31    37.32   0.72    51.50   1.04    
    ..Medicaid  11.44   0.22    9.08    0.33    9.07    0.31    11.99   0.33    21.32   0.63    28.37   1.05    
    ..Publically insured (no private)   11.79   0.20    7.67    0.30    8.57    0.28    13.17   0.30    26.43   0.76    37.27   1.21    
  .Uninsured    14.75   0.23    12.90   0.34    14.92   0.42    17.51   0.38    15.59   0.67    12.28   0.66    
People aged 0-64    "247,371"   *****   "96,563"    913 "77,129"    736 "52,013"    653 "15,666"    322 "6,000" 179 
  .Insured (any type)   83.36   0.26    86.68   0.35    83.81   0.45    78.73   0.45    77.41   0.92    79.97   1.03    
    ..Privately insured (alone or  in combination)  73.11   0.30    79.24   0.42    75.86   0.49    67.21   0.53    53.17   0.95    42.27   1.51    
    ..Medicare  1.83    0.06    0.19    0.03    0.52    0.06    1.90    0.12    10.29   0.50    22.32   1.05    
    ..Medicaid  11.69   0.25    9.24    0.34    9.47    0.34    13.10   0.42    24.25   0.80    34.81   1.48    
    ..Publically insured (no private)   10.25   0.21    7.44    0.30    7.94    0.29    11.52   0.33    24.24   0.83    37.70   1.43    
  .Uninsured    16.64   0.26    13.32   0.35    16.19   0.45    21.27   0.45    22.59   0.92    20.03   1.03    
People aged 18-64   "174,712"   *****   "55,534"    607 "57,342"    553 "41,977"    517 "14,113"    311 "5,747" 168 
  .Insured (any type)   82.54   0.26    86.33   0.37    84.00   0.40    77.95   0.48    76.63   0.97    79.45   1.08    
    ..Privately insured (alone or  in combination)  75.65   0.30    83.85   0.37    80.26   0.41    70.40   0.52    54.03   0.99    41.89   1.52    
    ..Medicare  2.59    0.08    0.32    0.05    0.70    0.08    2.35    0.15    11.42   0.56    23.30   1.06    
    ..Medicaid  7.02    0.19    2.91    0.18    4.16    0.21    7.85    0.32    21.51   0.79    33.75   1.53    
    ..Publically insured (no private)   6.89    0.17    2.48    0.15    3.74    0.18    7.55    0.28    22.59   0.82    37.56   1.44    
  .Uninsured    17.46   0.26    13.67   0.37    16.00   0.40    22.05   0.48    23.37   0.97    20.55   1.08    
People aged 65 and older    "33,742"    *****   "3,531" 117 "6,899" 186 "11,723"    211 "7,510" 175 "4,079" 138 
  .Insured (any type)   99.08   0.13    98.51   0.43    99.34   0.20    99.14   0.22    99.01   0.22    99.12   0.28    
    ..Privately insured (alone or  in combination)  75.99   0.60    84.51   1.39    83.80   0.94    78.64   0.89    68.02   1.24    62.48   1.79    
    ..Medicare  94.70   0.29    93.50   0.96    95.77   0.44    95.15   0.44    93.70   0.67    94.43   0.74    
    ..Medicaid  9.55    0.38    4.71    0.70    4.57    0.52    7.05    0.57    15.21   0.84    18.90   1.18    
    ..Publically insured (no private)   23.09   0.60    14.00   1.32    15.54   0.93    20.50   0.86    30.99   1.24    36.64   1.81    
  .Uninsured    0.92    0.13    1.49    0.43    0.66    0.20    0.86    0.22    0.99    0.22    0.88    0.28    
Family income less than 200 percent of poverty threshold\2  "94,310"    907 "27,954"    600 "25,543"    498 "23,801"    432 "11,392"    283 "5,621" 197 
  .Insured (any type)   73.93   0.44    75.44   0.74    71.27   0.93    70.74   0.72    77.58   1.04    84.70   1.01    
    ..Privately insured (alone or  in combination)  47.15   0.52    54.03   0.98    49.48   0.91    44.50   0.76    36.84   1.05    34.52   1.36    
    ..Medicare  15.41   0.24    3.51    0.24    8.72    0.44    18.96   0.56    36.14   1.09    47.98   1.34    
    ..Medicaid  26.38   0.50    24.69   0.89    23.25   0.80    24.73   0.77    34.17   1.02    40.24   1.51    
    ..Publically insured (no private)   26.78   0.48    21.41   0.86    21.79   0.80    26.23   0.64    40.74   1.17    50.19   1.52    
  .Uninsured    26.07   0.44    24.56   0.74    28.73   0.93    29.26   0.72    22.42   1.04    15.30   1.01    
Family income greater than or equal to 200 percent of poverty threshold\2   "186,434"   909 "71,968"    749 "58,398"    686 "39,852"    557 "11,778"    265 "4,438" 150 
  .Insured (any type)   91.00   0.18    91.65   0.30    91.15   0.30    89.53   0.38    91.01   0.56    91.76   0.84    
    ..Privately insured (alone or  in combination)  86.85   0.23    89.38   0.33    88.42   0.33    84.24   0.45    78.46   0.82    70.86   1.47    
    ..Medicare  11.77   0.13    3.47    0.14    8.19    0.23    19.15   0.39    38.47   0.92    56.21   1.57    
    ..Medicaid  3.80    0.15    2.93    0.18    2.81    0.19    4.28    0.27    8.86    0.60    13.28   1.11    
    ..Publically insured (no private)   4.15    0.13    2.27    0.14    2.73    0.15    5.29    0.30    12.55   0.74    20.90   1.40    
  .Uninsured    9.00    0.18    8.35    0.30    8.85    0.30    10.47   0.38    8.99    0.56    8.24    0.84
```

Error Message:

```
2015-12-11 22:21:21,360 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2015-12-11 22:21:21,364 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter], RULES_DISABLED=[FilterLogicExpressionSimplifier]}
2015-12-11 22:21:21,496 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
2015-12-11 22:21:21,542 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-12-11 22:21:21,556 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POLoad - Received error from loader function: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: java.lang.NullPointerException
2015-12-11 22:21:21,560 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2088: Fetch failed. Couldn't retrieve result
Details at logfile: /home/hadoop/ashwin/data/pig_1449899080960.log
```

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help me out on this? Thanks.